# how to define cycles in protobuf?

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

say i have the following mode.proto file:

```
message EntityD {
    optional EntityE ePointer = 1;
    optional int32 dField = 2;
}

message EntityE {
    optional EntityD dPointer = 1;
    optional int32 eField = 2;
}
```

this has 2 entities - D and E, which allow cross-linking. my issue is that after generating java code from the above *.proto im unable to create a cycle:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Model.EntityD.Builder dBuilder = Model.EntityD.newBuilder();
    Model.EntityE.Builder eBuilder = Model.EntityE.newBuilder();

    dBuilder.setDField(42);
    eBuilder.setEField(7);
    dBuilder.setEPointer(eBuilder);
    eBuilder.setDPointer(dBuilder);

    Model.EntityD d = dBuilder.build();
    Model.EntityE e = eBuilder.build();

    System.err.println("same d: "+(d==e.getDPointer()));
    System.err.println("same e: "+(e==d.getEPointer()));
}
```

im trying to create a simple D <--> E cycle. instead i get this:

```
same d: false 
same e: false
```

[image]

there *IS* a cycle in the created model, but only starting with a certain depth.

is this an issue with probuf-generated java code?
does protobuf officially support cycles in the graph ?
whats the expected result for this in other protobuf "output" languages? (namely c++)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The protobuf format does not include object identity, and there is no notion of reference / graph support. It is a basic tree only. Anything beyond that would be implementation specific and not part of the specification.

Basically, don't do that.

This is not uncommon: the same is true of many serializers, including XML and json serializers. And for these cases, again, some implementations may have support for a local definition of identity - but it is not guaranteed in the general case.

Comment: i think the reason cycle support is lacking in xml and json is because the underlying "wire format" (xml and json) has no built-in notion of a "reference". i'd certainly expect a serialization framework that defines its own binary wire format to support cyclic references (java serialization, for example). was this never even proposed as a feature?

Comment: as an added corollary your own protobuf serialization format has reference tracking, so there's obviously demand ...

Comment: @radai to confirm: indeed it is not in the spec. Yes it gets mentioned occasionally, but so far has not been implemented, except for implementation-specific hacks, like mine :)

Comment: Cycles add a huge amount of complication to any serialization format. Detecting them requires maintaining some kind of hash table which would be quite expensive, and the receiving end would need extra bookkeeping as well. The vast majority of use cases would gain nothing from this extra cost. Moreover, it could be a security problem: if a receiver is expecting some sort of tree and unexpectedly gets a cycle instead, they could easily get stuck in an infinite loop. For all these reasons, most serialization protocols (whether text or binary) don't support them.

Comment: Oh, also, cycles would add lots of complication in languages like C++ which are not garbage collected and so depend on tracking ownership for memory management.

Comment: @radai please note Kenton's comments above - not sure you will have got a notification

Comment: @KentonVarda - the discussion is kinda hypothetical at this point, but as to the security problem - when application A wants to talk to application B they should agree on the format (especially in protobuf, which is strong typed), including whether or not loops are allowed and where, so loops arent really an "attack". about the extra complication - its the cost of cycles. not specific to protobuf. this could be a good argument for never allowing loops in datamodels in general, but once you have a datamodel that does youre obviouslt willing to pay the price.

Comment: @radai - I could see an argument for supporting backreferences if you have to explicitly declare in the schema where they are allowed. That solves most of the problems. In my experience, though, the demand for this is pretty low, and in the few cases where you do have such a data set, it's not so bad to send an array of objects that refer to each other by index.